# Creating page layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

i want to prepare a few template. When user select one, layout must change.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/163/layoutselection.png/

How can i do this with javascript? Also it must be responsive.

Can anyone send an example or sample code?

Comment: Your in the wrong place buddy

Comment: You're going to have problems here - this is not so much a questions as "please do my work for me".

You need to learn some things for yourself about how JS works, find some examples and see how they're done, then come back *if* you have some real questions.

Comment: Because this is a place to come to get help with code you are working on yourself.. Not to get others to do it for you.

Comment: Come on guys, it's not that bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responsive designs are not that easy that someone could just give you a boilerplate code.

You need to define the problem you are facing:

You have a webpage with a fixed markup, and you want only it's layout to change by javascript?

What is your markup, what is your css by default?

How many parts of the page should be "moving around"? Which goes where in which case?

For example: It's a little hard to order the same markup to layout 6 and 7 (on the linked image), as in layout 6 there are 2 parts of the page and in layout 7 there are 5.

Tell us what you have done before:

Do you have any design yet? Are you just researching in the subject and yet to find good examples? Are you having trouble with your project?

I have the impression that you do not really know what you want and what options do you have.

So I advise you to read this about responsive design. What it is and how it is done.

For example this is a good starting point: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Thanks for your reply

I have 10 different layout like that:
#container {
width: 800px;
padding:0px;
margin: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#outer { 
border-left: solid 200px #EBD3E0;  
background-color: #ffffff; }
#inner {margin:0 px; width:100%; } 
#content { position: relative;  margin: 0px; }


Also now i can create them with using javascipt
Examplecode: 
 $("<div>").attr("id","myDivID").css({"position":"absolute", "width":"300px", "height":"300px","border":"solid 1px red" }).appendTo("body");

Comment: Because i want to do drag&drop functionallity.
I want to add small 2 or 3 coloumns div into layout with drag&drop. So, they must be responsive too.

I will read documentation about responsive design. Thanks everybody

Comment: If you liked my answer you should consider upvoting or accepting it.